# MySql query to pull 2 different data from a single column and display them separately in 2 columns

Tags: mysql

```
name         value   

FirstName    Anan
LastName     kumar
.             .
.             .  
.             .
```

i have a table in my database like this.i have entered only few values. i want to display the table like

```
FirstName          LastName

 Anand             Kumar
  .                  .
  .                  .
```

For that can you please give me the mysql query.

Comment: You can parse them using MySQL string functions - SUBSTRING_INDEX(column1, ' ', 1) and SUBSTRING_INDEX(column1, ' ', -1).

Comment: You should edit a question to add details instead of posting duplicates.

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySql query to pull 2different data from a single column and display them separetely in 2 column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497479/mysql-query-to-pull-2different-data-from-a-single-column-and-display-them-separet)

Comment: I have merged the edits and answers from your duplicates into this question. Please, do **not** post it again.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT
`name` , 
SUBSTRING_INDEX( `name` , ' ', 1 ) AS fname,
SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX( `name` , ' ', 2 ),' ',-1) AS lname
FROM yourtable
```

from here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html

Answer (score 0):

```
select
    id, other,
    max(case when name = 'firstname' then value end) FirstName,
    max(case when name = 'lastname' then value end) LastName
from tbl
group by
    id, other
```

Classic pivot case. You group by every field except for name and type, then use the MAX(CASE) to merged the two records into one row.

Comment: Wouldn't self-join be faster?

Comment: In rare cases, maybe. Normally, a single pass using group-by is faster than having to do any join at all.

Comment: @pritosh / Why don't you edit the question with what you have tried?